# PL/SQL Creating Associative Array With Employee Id as Key

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, associative-array

I am trying to create a hash with `employee_id (NUMBER(6,0))` as the key and `salary (NUMBER(8,2))` as the value.

For that I have created a INDEX-OF table(associative array) in PL/SQL (Oracle 11g)  using the following definition:

```
TYPE emp_title_hash IS TABLE OF employees.salary%type 
                       INDEX BY employees.employee_id%type;
```

I am getting the following compilation error:

```
Error(22,28): PLS-00315: Implementation restriction: unsupported table index type
```

I am aware in this case that the only supported type for the index is `STRING` or `PLS_INTEGER`. This seems to really restrictive. Why exactly has this been imposed in Oracle ?  Is there a work around to get the above done ?

Appreciate your comments / suggestions.

Comment: Because that's the way it is.  Why can't you index by varchar2 and convert your hash value to a string instead?

Comment: The idea was to implement a faster means of looking up salary given any employee id , instead of querying the db every single time. Hence i wanted a hash where the key would be an employee id.

Comment: Are you suggesting I typecast the key and value to the required types ?

Comment: Why can't you index by `PLS_INTEGER`, for that matter. `number(6,0)` would fit within the valid range; what do you gain by restricting it further?.

Comment: Do as @OldProgrammer suggests, convert your employee ID to a string, and use said string as the index. While greater flexibility would be nice, the existing functionality is sufficient for your use. HOWEVER - unless and until you've got a real, live performance problem on your hands I suggest that going to the database would be a better solution. Remember: the best time to optimize is never; the second-best time to optimize is when you have an actual performance issue; the WORST time to optimize is when you're guessing at what will slow the code down. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone already pointed out, you can use "index by pls_integer", since pls_integer can contain any number(6,0) value.

Surely it would be nice to be able to use any possible type to index a pl/sql associative array, but I have always managed a way of writing a function that builds a string that identifies the object instance I want to use as index value.

So, instead of writing:

```
 type TMyAssociativeArray is table of MyDataType index by MyIndexType;
```

I write:

```
  Type TMyAssociativeArray is table of MyDataType index by varchar2(30);
```

then I write a function that calculates a unique string from MyIndexType:

```
function GetHash(obj MyIndexType) return varchar2;
```

and, having written this function I can use it to simulate an associative array indexed by MyIndexType object:

so I can write

```
 declare
     arr TMyAssociativeArray;
     obj TMyDataType;
     idx TMyDataType;
 begin 
     ....
     arr(GetHash(idx)) := obj;
 end;
```

Here I am getting out of the strict question you asked, and giving you an advice about a possible other way of obtaining a quick customer->salary lookup cache... This is the final purpose of your associative-array question, as I can read from your comment, so maybe this could be useful:

If you are using associative arrays to build a fast look-up mechanism, *and if you can use the oracle 11g R2 new features*, a easier way of obtaining this caching is to rely on the native RESULT_CACHE feature which has been introduced both for queries (by using the RESULT_CACHE hint) and for pl/sql functions.

for pl/sql functions you can create a function whose result value is cached like this one:

```
 create or replace function cached_employee_salary(employee number) 
 return number RESULT_CACHE is
     result number;
 begin
    select salary 
    into result 
    from employees e
    where e.code = employee;
    return result;
 end;
```

the RESULT_CACHE keyword instructs oracle to keep an in-memory cache of the result values and to reuse them on subsequent calls (when the function is called with the same parameters, of course).

this cache has these advantages, compared to the use of associative arrays:

1. it is shared among all sessions: cached data is not kept in the private memory allocated for each session, so it wastes less memory
2. oracle is smart enough to detect that the function calculates its results by accessing the employees table and automatically invalidates the cached results if the table data is being modified.

Of course I suggest you to run some tests to see if this optimization, in your case gives some tangible results. it mostly depends on how complex is the calculation you make in your function.

You can also rely on an analogous feature introduced for SQL queries, triggered by the   /*+RESULT_CACHE*/ hint:

```
    select /*+RESULT_CACHE*/
            salary 
    from employees e
    where e.code = employee;
    return result
```

this hint instructs oracle to store and reuse (on subsequent executions) the result set of the query. it will be stored too in memory.
actually this hint has also the advantage that, being the hint -syntactically speaking- a special comment, this query will continue working without any modifications even on servers < 11gR2, whereas, for the function cache version, you should use some "conditional compilation" magic to make it compile also with previous server versions (for which it would be a normal function without any result caching)

I Hope this helps.